# How to insert anonymous functionality into an extended class?

Tags: php, oop

I have a base controller that looks something like this:

```
<?php
namespace framework;

class BaseController
{
    public $model;
    public $view;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new ModelFactory();
        $this->view = new View($this->model->data);
    }
}
```

This controller is never called directly, but only through `extends`:

```
<?php
namespace framework\controllers;

use framework\BaseController,
    framework\Router;

class IndexController extends BaseController
{
}
```

What I'd like to do, and hopefully this makes sense, is insert data or extra functionality into the base controller between `$this->model` and `$this->view` in such a way that it's anonymous or decoupled, rather than hard-coded. As an example, the application may or may not require user data. The following is how I could hard code it although this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid:

```
<?php
namespace framework;

class BaseController
{
    public $model;
    public $view;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new ModelFactory();

        // get user data
        $this->model->data['user_roles'] = array();
        if ($user = $this->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->model->data['user_roles'] = $user->roles;
        }

        $this->view = new View($this->model->data);
    }

    // check if a user is logged in and return a user object or false
    public function isLoggedIn() {}
}
```

And the following is pseudo code of what my brain thinks I'd like to accomplish:

```
// anonymous function in my bootstrap or global configuration file
$user_roles = function () {};

<?php
namespace framework;

class BaseController
{
    public $model;
    public $view;

    function __construct($name, $value) // not sure how these are passed in
    {
        $this->model = new ModelFactory();

        // get extra data
        $this->model->data[$name] = $value($this->model);

        $this->view = new View($this->model->data);
    }
}
```

Not sure if I need a specific pattern or if I'm even heading in the right direction. How can I accomplish something along these lines? I open to any recommended alternative approaches.

Comment: The entire problem you are having right now all boils down to having something called `BaseController` which makes little sense.

Comment: Also you are worried about coupling but the entire purpose (based on your code) of the `BaseController` is tight coupling.

Comment: The way 'AURA framework' gets around this, is to have an extra parameter to the constructor  called '$options = array();' that gets put into a property  and can be accesses with a `getOptions();` method. This allows you to pass anything extra to the controller and access it from the child classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are [PHP traits](http://php.net/Traits).

Traits are a way to extract/isolate behavior which you can then "inject" in any class.

When you declare a trait:

```
trait ControllerQueryable
{
  public function magicQuery()
  { // $this is the class that's using this trait.
    $this->orm->fetch(str_replace(get_class($this), 'Controller', ''), $this->params['id']);
  }
}
```

It's made available for any class to `use`:

```
class BlogController extends BaseController
{
  use ControllerQueryable;

  public function showAction()
  {
    $model = $this->magicQuery();
    // yada yada yada
  }
}
```

Contrarily to `extends`, you can `use` as many traits as you want.

Comment: If you use traits, I recommend to also use interfaces with them since traits do not enable you to use `instanceof` by themselves.

Comment: @Ven Would you consider [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BhQvZnwP) (based on my example) to be a correct or acceptable implementation of your answer?

Comment: Yes. Although you might want to not expose the internals that much :)